# How to determine type of nested data structures in Python?

Tags: python, types

I am currently translating some Python to F#, specifically [neural-networks-and-deep-learning](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning) .

To make sure the data structures are correctly translated the details of the nested types from Python are needed. The [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function is working for simple types but not for nested types.

For example in Python:

```py
> data = ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],["a","b","c"])
> type(data)
<type 'tuple'>
```

only gives the type of the first level. Nothing is known about the arrays in the tuple.

I was hoping for something like what F# does

```ml
> let data = ([|[|1;2;3|];[|4;5;6|];[|7;8;9|]|],[|"a";"b";"c"|]);;

val data : int [] [] * string [] =
  ([|[|1; 2; 3|]; [|4; 5; 6|]; [|7; 8; 9|]|], [|"a"; "b"; "c"|])
```

returning the signature independent of the value

> int [] [] * string []
>
> ```
> *         is a tuple item separator  
> int [] [] is a two dimensional jagged array of int  
> string [] is a one dimensional array of string
> ```

Can or how is this done in Python?

TLDR;

Currently I am using PyCharm with the debugger and in the variables window clicking the view option for an individual variable to see the details. The problem is that the output contains the values along with the types intermixed and I only need the type signature. When the variables are like (float[50000][784], int[50000]) the values get in the way. Yes I am resizing the variables for now, but that is a workaround and not a solution.

e.g.

Using [PyCharm Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

```
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ...,     
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32),
  array([7, 2, 1, ..., 4, 5, 6]))
```

Using [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder)

[image: Using Spyder variable viewer]

Using [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) with [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/)

```
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],    
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],  
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],  
        ...,   
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],  
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],  
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32),  
  array([5, 0, 4, ..., 8, 4, 8], dtype=int64))
```

EDIT:

Since this question has been stared someone is apparently looking for more details, here is my modified version which can also handle [numpy ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). Thanks to [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469220/vlad) for the initial version.

Also because of the use of a variation of [Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) there is no more use of ? for heterogeneous types.

```
# Note: Typing for elements of iterable types such as Set, List, or Dict 
# use a variation of Run Length Encoding.

def type_spec_iterable(iterable, name):
    def iterable_info(iterable):
        # With an iterable for it to be comparable 
        # the identity must contain the name and length 
        # and for the elements the type, order and count.
        length = 0
        types_list = []
        pervious_identity_type = None
        pervious_identity_type_count = 0
        first_item_done = False
        for e in iterable:
            item_type = type_spec(e)
            if (item_type != pervious_identity_type):
                if not first_item_done:
                    first_item_done = True
                else:
                    types_list.append((pervious_identity_type, pervious_identity_type_count))
                pervious_identity_type = item_type
                pervious_identity_type_count = 1
            else:
                pervious_identity_type_count += 1
            length += 1
        types_list.append((pervious_identity_type, pervious_identity_type_count))
        return (length, types_list)
    (length, identity_list) = iterable_info(iterable)
    element_types = ""
    for (identity_item_type, identity_item_count) in identity_list:
        if element_types == "":
            pass
        else:
            element_types += ","
        element_types += identity_item_type
        if (identity_item_count != length) and (identity_item_count != 1):
            element_types += "[" + `identity_item_count` + "]"
    result = name + "[" + `length` + "]<" + element_types + ">"
    return result

def type_spec_dict(dict, name):
    def dict_info(dict):
        # With a dict for it to be comparable 
        # the identity must contain the name and length 
        # and for the key and value combinations the type, order and count.
        length = 0
        types_list = []
        pervious_identity_type = None
        pervious_identity_type_count = 0
        first_item_done = False
        for (k, v) in dict.iteritems():
            key_type = type_spec(k)
            value_type = type_spec(v)
            item_type = (key_type, value_type)
            if (item_type != pervious_identity_type):
                if not first_item_done:
                    first_item_done = True
                else:
                    types_list.append((pervious_identity_type, pervious_identity_type_count))
                pervious_identity_type = item_type
                pervious_identity_type_count = 1
            else:
                pervious_identity_type_count += 1
            length += 1
        types_list.append((pervious_identity_type, pervious_identity_type_count))
        return (length, types_list)
    (length, identity_list) = dict_info(dict)
    element_types = ""
    for ((identity_key_type,identity_value_type), identity_item_count) in identity_list:
        if element_types == "":
            pass
        else:
            element_types += ","
        identity_item_type = "(" + identity_key_type + "," + identity_value_type + ")"
        element_types += identity_item_type
        if (identity_item_count != length) and (identity_item_count != 1):
            element_types += "[" + `identity_item_count` + "]"
    result = name + "[" + `length` + "]<" + element_types + ">"
    return result

def type_spec_tuple(tuple, name):
    return name + "<" + ", ".join(type_spec(e) for e in tuple) + ">"

def type_spec(obj):
    object_type = type(obj)
    name = object_type.__name__
    if (object_type is int) or (object_type is long) or (object_type is str) or (object_type is bool) or (object_type is float):            
        result = name
    elif object_type is type(None):
        result = "(none)"
    elif (object_type is list) or (object_type is set):
        result = type_spec_iterable(obj, name)
    elif (object_type is dict):
        result = type_spec_dict(obj, name)
    elif (object_type is tuple):
        result = type_spec_tuple(obj, name)
    else:
        if name == 'ndarray':
            ndarray = obj
            ndarray_shape = "[" + `ndarray.shape`.replace("L","").replace(" ","").replace("(","").replace(")","") + "]"
            ndarray_data_type = `ndarray.dtype`.split("'")[1]
            result = name + ndarray_shape + "<" + ndarray_data_type + ">"
        else:
            result = "Unknown type: " , name
    return result
```

I would not consider it done, but it has worked on everything I needed thus far.

Comment: You might be able to hack yourself something together for tuples, but not for lists or dicts, as they are untyped (tuples too, but at least they're immutable). What's supposed to be the type of `[1, 2, 'c']`?

Comment: Does `data` come from a predictable, structured source? Or is it really just chance?

Comment: Are you trying to deduce the types from variables in a running script, or deduce them from the code itself?  It's one thing to produce a list or tuple, and then iterate through it noting the type at each level.  It's quite another to look at code, and deduce what it produces (without running it).

Comment: @Monkpit For the tutorial I am working with the data comes from [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and is known as the Hello World of Neural Networks.

Comment: @hpaulj I would prefer the type signatures by looking at the code but do realize the type system of Python is not static. Since this is a relatively simple project I will do it any way possible. At present I run the code and use the debugger or for simple code fragments use an interactive session. If I work with Python more in the future this will be a question I expect to refer back to often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it by hand would be:

```
def type_spec_iterable(obj, name):
    tps = set(type_spec(e) for e in obj)
    if len(tps) == 1:
        return name + "<" + next(iter(tps)) + ">"
    else:
        return name + "<?>"


def type_spec_dict(obj):
    tps = set((type_spec(k), type_spec(v)) for (k,v) in obj.iteritems())
    keytypes = set(k for (k, v) in tps)
    valtypes =  set(v for (k, v) in tps)
    kt = next(iter(keytypes)) if len(keytypes) == 1 else "?"
    vt = next(iter(valtypes)) if len(valtypes) == 1 else "?"
    return "dict<%s, %s>" % (kt, vt)


def type_spec_tuple(obj):
    return "tuple<" + ", ".join(type_spec(e) for e in obj) + ">"


def type_spec(obj):
    t = type(obj)
    res = {
        int: "int",
        str: "str",
        bool: "bool",
        float: "float",
        type(None): "(none)",
        list: lambda o: type_spec_iterable(o, 'list'),
        set: lambda o: type_spec_iterable(o, 'set'),
        dict: type_spec_dict,
        tuple: type_spec_tuple,
    }.get(t, lambda o: type(o).__name__)
    return res if type(res) is str else res(obj)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Foo(object):
        pass
    for obj in [
        1,
        2.3,
        None,
        False,
        "hello",
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["a", "b"],
        [1, "h"],
        (False, 1, "2"),
        set([1.2, 2.3, 3.4]),
        [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
        [(1,'a'), (2, 'b')],
        {1:'b', 2:'c'},
        [Foo()], # todo - inheritance?
    ]:
        print repr(obj), ":", type_spec(obj)
```

This prints:

```
1 : int
2.3 : float
None : (none)
False : bool
'hello' : str
[1, 2, 3] : list<int>
['a', 'b'] : list<str>
[1, 'h'] : list<?>
(False, 1, '2') : tuple<bool, int, str>
set([2.3, 1.2, 3.4]) : set<float>
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] : list<list<int>>
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')] : list<tuple<int, str>>
{1: 'b', 2: 'c'} : dict<int, str>
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x101de6c50>] : list<Foo>
```

There's a question of how far you want to take it, and how deeply to check, with trade-offs between speed and accuracy. For example, do you want to go through all the items in a large list? Do you want to handle custom types (and tracking down common ancestors of those types)?

Worth a read, though I'm not sure it's applicable, this PEP on [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: Nice detail. Python is not a language I use often so I will have to try this and spend some time understanding it. There is enough meat here for me dig in an enjoy. Did you write this up after the question? If so I'm impressed, if you just copy and pasted with changes then OK.

Comment: I wrote it from scratch after the question. I haven't looked online, but I assume someone must have done something like this before.

Comment: I'm surprised there was not a standard answer for this. I am not use to working with duck typing, so this is a learning experience for me.

Comment: With duck typing, you can go a long time with errors in your code and not notice because you haven't run that part of the code. But Python's amazing for when you need to get something done really quickly, in the time you would have set up includes and a `main()` in C, you're already done writing your code.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the types in `type_spec`, instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: It's a valid point, what i did is slow. Wasn't sure whether types are hashable or not. If yes, then that would be the right way to do it. Maybe an identity hashmap otherwise?

Comment: Languages with an interactive environment (REPL) definitely get a plus.

Comment: @Vlad Types are indeed hashable.

Comment: @L3viathan: used a dictionary instead

Comment: @Vlad With regards to PEP 0484. Wile the lint does not make use of the types during the run of the code, I find that adding asserts such as `assert type(x) == y` is just as useful. Maybe there should be a new PEP that converts the type info into asserts that will run during the run of the code. If you have ever done Untyped Lambda Calculus and then Type Lambda Calculus it should make more sense.

Comment: That would be brilliant. I suppose it would make more sense e.g. during testing than in production, for performance reasons, but it would be great to have it.

Answer (score 5):

As I commented, this is impossible in Python, because lists are untyped.

You can still pretend to do it:

```
def typ(something, depth=0):
    if depth > 63:
        return "..."
    if type(something) == tuple:
        return "<class 'tuple': <" + ", ".join(typ(ding, depth+1) for ding in something) + ">>"
    elif type(something) == list:
        return "<class 'list': " + (typ(something[0], depth+1) if something else '(empty)') + ">"
    else:
        return str(type(something))
```

That returns the string `<class 'tuple': <<class 'list': <class 'list': <class 'int'>>>,<class 'list': <class 'str'>>>>` for your example.

**edit:** To make it look more like F# you could do this instead:

```
def typ(something, depth=0):
    if depth > 63:
        return "..."
    if type(something) == tuple:
        return " * ".join(typ(ding, depth+1) for ding in something)
    elif type(something) == list:
        return (typ(something[0]) if something else 'empty') + " []"
    else:
        return str(type(something, depth+1)).split("'")[1]
```

which will return `int [] [] * str []` in your example.

Comment: Thanks. I will spend some time with this.

Comment: @GuyCoder I added an alternative, more concise version (since we're not pythonic anyways here).